# creating a tic tac toe code with a class but only for the board display and defining the player

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi so i have just recently started learning c++ and any help would be appreciated in my problem.

- I've been asked to create a piece of code for a game (chosen tic tac toe)
- but its divided between two people.
- my role is to create a class for only the displaying of the board and the choosing of player x or player o.

so far i have tried creating this c++ code but errors keep showing, anyone know how to correct this??
p.s in the game i class it as XsandOs.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class XsandOs // Name of the class
{
public:

    XsandOs();

    void drawboard();
    void printBoard();
    void getMove(int move);
    void choosePlayer(char player);
    bool checkwinner(const char board[3][3], char symbol, int plays);

private:
    const char board[3][3];

};

void XsandOs::drawboard // Develops the board 
{
    cout << "Let's play X's and O's\n" << "_________________________________\n\n"; //This prints a title declaring the name of the game
    //This action uses an array to create the board, the user will choose the number to select where they want the character to go.

    char board[3][3] =
    {
        { '1', '2', '3', }; //This creates the top row
        {'4', '5', '6', }; // This creates the middle row
        {'7', '8', '9', }; // This creates the bottom row
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            cout << board[i][j] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void XsandOs::choosePlayer(char player)
{
    if (player == 'X')
        Player = 'O';
    elseif(player == 'O')
        Player = 'X';

    return(void);
}

int main()
{
    draw();

    while (1)
    {
        input();
        draw();
        choosePlayer();
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before and can save you a lot of time. "The only winning move is not to play."

Comment: I can't see the link between main() and the class. Have you put a `#` before the include for iostream ?

Comment: `void XsandOs::drawboard` should be `void XsandOs::drawboard()`

Comment: Where did you see this: `return(void);` ? It's `return void();` or just `return;`

Comment: And the semicolons need to be removed from the middle of the array definition. Whole load of stuff that's outright wrong here. Recommend hitting the text again and boning up on syntax.

Comment: @Christophe I think that's just a formatting error. The include wasn't indented enough to be treated as code.

Comment: @user4581301 I was talking about `draw()` and `input()` which are not defined,  and `choosePlayer()` which is used without an object.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments, really appreciate it, i've made the changes recommended but still a little confused on what do you mean by boning up on syntax and how do you define the draw(), input() and choosePlayer()

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up some of the design issues and created methods for you.   There is still work to be done, you can't expect us to do it for you.   Good luck.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class XsandOs // Name of the class
{
public:

    XsandOs();

    void draw();
    void input();
    int getMove(); // 1-9 or zero on error
    void choosePlayer();
    bool checkWinner(); // true means game over

private:
    char board[3][3];
    char player;
};

XsandOs::XsandOs()
{
    // initialize the board
    player = 'X'; // x goes first
    for (int i = 0;i < 3;++i)
        for (int j = 0;j < 3;++j)
            board[i][j] = ' ';  // blank means the spot is empty
}

void XsandOs::draw() // Develops the board 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int XsandOs::getMove()
{
    // ask for a move
    // validate the move or get a new move 
    // TODO       
}
void XsandOs::input()
{
    // ask for a move
    int move = 0;
    while (!move) {
        move = getMove();
    }

    // do the move and update the board
    board[move-1] = player;
}

void XsandOs::choosePlayer()
{
    if (player == 'X')
        Player = 'O';
    elseif(player == 'O')
        Player = 'X';
}

bool XsandOs::checkWinner()
{
    // TODO
    // Check the board state and look for a winner.
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    XsandOs game;
    bool gameOver = false;
    game.draw();
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        game.input();
        game.draw();
        game.checkWinner()
        gameOver = game.choosePlayer();
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```